Python (Jupyter) Notebook in browser: no horizontal scrollbar at the bottom of a cell?
I use python notebook (browser) often.
There's a vertical scrollbar on a cell, but no horizontal scrollbar to allow me to access columns on the right side of a cell:

The only way I found to see columns on the right is to select text in the displayed dataframe, and drag the mouse to the right.
I've tried pandas options:
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 70)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)
from IPython.display import display, HTML
display(HTML("<style>.container { width:100% !important; }</style>"))

I've even tried full screen, and dragging the 'expand' icon on a cell, nothing works.
Am I missing something really obvious ?

You can scroll horizontally by holding down Shift while you scroll with your scroll wheel. Trackpads should be able to scroll horizontally simply using 2-finger gestures.

For the record, you can toggle the view mode by clicking in the side to the left of the dataframe there. The mode shown corresponds to "metadata": { "scrolled": true ..., I believe. If you save the notebook file when it is like that and open the saved .ipynb in your favorite code text editor, you should see something like "scrolled": true for that cell when it is left in that mode. However, in that mode, you should be able to scroll a dataframe horizontal you try, like Abirbhav G says. The browser doesn't make a visual of it there until you engage with it. Should.

Thanks @AbirbhavG. but that doesn't seem to work for me.

Thanks @Wayne, I did enable scrolling - but all that does is either display the max rows (if scrolling is False) or shorten the cell display but show a scroll bar (if scrolling is True). So far, no possibility to scroll to the right unless I select text and drag the mouse.

Hmmm... I wonder if it is your installation or browser? Can you try in sessions launched from here? Press 'launch binder' there to start up the session. Let me know if you need code to easily bring in wide Pandas dataframe.
